Populate balance for missing days
I have a table holding the daily balances of each account, but only on days on which there has been a transaction on the account. For the following account for example :
 account_id |          updated_at           | balance 
------------+-------------------------------+---------
 7          | 2024-03-14 23:51:12.430866+00 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-15 23:44:34.791627+00 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-16 23:38:02.437022+00 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-17 23:56:52.592801+00 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-17 23:56:52.592801+00 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-17 23:56:52.592801+00 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-17 23:56:52.592801+00 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-17 23:56:52.592801+00 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-20 17:47:04.989205+00 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-20 17:47:04.989205+00 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-21 19:27:48.242602+00 |  357.27
 7          | 2024-03-22 16:19:17.737126+00 |  325.83
 7          | 2024-03-23 18:09:37.164425+00 |  325.83
 7          | 2024-03-24 22:45:58.444256+00 |  325.83
 7          | 2024-03-24 22:45:58.444256+00 |  325.83
 7          | 2024-03-25 16:46:49.831235+00 |  221.22
 7          | 2024-03-26 15:32:09.949961+00 |  150.39
 7          | 2024-03-27 21:58:14.160818+00 |  150.39
 7          | 2024-03-28 19:23:19.219855+00 |  127.08
 7          | 2024-03-29 17:33:07.109838+00 |  160.47
 7          | 2024-03-30 17:49:41.642925+00 |  210.47
 7          | 2024-04-01 16:53:34.900447+00 |  300.47

I have no entries on dates March 18th, 2024 and March 19th, 2024.
I am trying to build a table that contains the balance for all the days up to yesterday including the missing dates in the previous table. The expected result is:
 account_id | updated_at | balance 
------------+------------+---------
 7          | 2024-03-14 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-15 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-16 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-17 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-18 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-19 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-20 |     400
 7          | 2024-03-21 |  357.27
 7          | 2024-03-22 |  325.83
 7          | 2024-03-23 |  325.83
 7          | 2024-03-24 |  325.83
 7          | 2024-03-25 |  221.22
 7          | 2024-03-26 |  150.39
 7          | 2024-03-27 |  150.39
 7          | 2024-03-28 |  127.08
 7          | 2024-03-29 |  160.47
 7          | 2024-03-30 |  210.47
 7          | 2024-04-01 |  300.47
 ....

And the table would continue up to yesterday.
Based on this thread, I wrote the following code snippet :
WITH days AS (
        SELECT generate_series('2024-03-01'::DATE, (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 DAY')::DATE, '1 day'::INTERVAL)::DATE AS date_
    )

    , discontinued_days AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            account_id
            , balance
            , days.date_
            , updated_at
        FROM days LEFT JOIN my_balance_table
        ON days.date_ >= my_balance_table.updated_at::DATE
    )                                                          
    
    , grouped AS (                                             
        SELECT
            account_id
            , balance
            , date_
            , updated_at
            , COUNT(account_id) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY date_) AS grp
        FROM discontinued_days                                
    )                                                         
                                                              
    SELECT DISTINCT                                           
        account_id                                                
        , COALESCE(MIN(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id, grp ORDER BY date_), 0) AS balance
        , date_                                                                                                       
    FROM grouped    

It works well for the days up to March 28th, however on March 29th, it returns a balance of 127.08  while it is expected to see 160.47 because that is the balance that we see in the input table my_balance_table. And the same happens for the days after March 29th:
 account_id | balance |   date_    
------------+---------+------------
 7          |     400 | 2024-03-14
 7          |     400 | 2024-03-15
 7          |     400 | 2024-03-16
 7          |     400 | 2024-03-17
 7          |     400 | 2024-03-18
 7          |     400 | 2024-03-19
 7          |     400 | 2024-03-20
 7          |  357.27 | 2024-03-21
 7          |  325.83 | 2024-03-22
 7          |  325.83 | 2024-03-23
 7          |  325.83 | 2024-03-24
 7          |  221.22 | 2024-03-25
 7          |  150.39 | 2024-03-26
 7          |  150.39 | 2024-03-27
 7          |  127.08 | 2024-03-28
 7          |  127.08 | 2024-03-29
 7          |  127.08 | 2024-03-30
 7          |  127.08 | 2024-03-31
 7          |  127.08 | 2024-04-01

How to fix this ?
EDIT May 31st, 2024
I tried the second solution from the thread above using an index. It gives the correct result in the example 7 above however scanning the full my_balance_table takes a lot of time (i.e performance is poor). Here are the commands I used:
CREATE INDEX my_balance_table_multi_idx ON my_balance_table (account_id, updated_at::DATE DESC, created_at) INCLUDE (balance);


WITH days AS (
        SELECT generate_series('2024-03-01'::DATE, (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 DAY')::DATE, '1 day'::INTERVAL)::DATE AS date_
    )

    SELECT DISTINCT
        account_id
        , COALESCE(b.balance, 0) AS balance
        , days.date_
    FROM days INNER JOIN my_balance_table outer_
    ON outer_.created_at <= days.date_
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT balance
        FROM my_balance_table inner_
        WHERE inner_.account_id = outer_.account_id
        -- AND inner_.updated_at::DATE <= days.date_
        AND inner_.updated_at::DATE < days.date_ + INTERVAL '1 DAY'
        ORDER BY inner_.updated_at::DATE DESC                   
        LIMIT 1                          
    ) b ON TRUE
    ORDER BY bba_id, days.date_


Don't make it so complicated with DISTINCT and COUNTs. Just use the LAG() window function?

I tried but could not make it work. Do you know how to use it ?

Does this achieve what you want? It's exactly the first approach from the answer you had linked (sans the join against the account table)

I noticed LAG() (alone) does not work nicely since you don't just want to fill in missing days, but also aggregate multiple updates from a single day into just one row, so you need a subquery or group by anyway.

@Bergi i tried LEFT JOIN LATERAL but the performance is poor, the query won't return anything even after setting the index (CREATE INDEX my_balance_table_multi_idx ON my_balance_table (account_id, updated_at DESC, balance);

If I could make it run quickly, then it could be a solution because filtering my_balance_table to only the account given as example in this thread yields the expected result

Ah I see now what you tried to do with those count() things, given that COALESCE(b.balance, LAG(b.balance) FILTER (WHERE balance IS NOT NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY as_of_date)) is still not implemented in Postgres :-(

an update for people coming here. I ended up using the first solution from
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133416/188406 after setting the index. The query don'r return in few seconds, but it returns in less then 15m !

@dada: A query like that doesn't get seconds in my book! :)

a remark 15m on the full my_balance_table

@dada Wait why are you doing two joins against my_balance_table? Notice that in the linked answer, the first join is against the accounts table. If you don't have one, you could substitute (SELECT account_id FROM my_balance_table GROUP BY account_id) or (SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM my_balance_table).

"Day"

I am trying to build a table that contains the balance for all the days

Let's first address a lurking problem. You have a timestamptz column, which has no notion of "days". You must set the time zone that defines your days. Else the query depends on the timezone setting of the current session - which "works", until it doesn't.
There are various ways to get that right. In the below query, I assume time zone 'UTC' and generate day boundaries accordingly.

Selecting today's rows based on UTC time

Index
You commented:

... performance is poor [...] even after setting the index
CREATE INDEX my_balance_table_multi_idx ON my_balance_table (account_id, updated_at DESC, balance);

The index cannot be used. Your query filters on the expression updated_at::DATE, applied to the table column. That rules out above index in any case. Moreover, it rules out any index because that expression depends on the timezone setting of the current session. So it's not immutable and can't be indexed as such. Don't formulate filters that way. Use sargable expressions. Then a fitting index works wonders. Even slightly better:
CREATE INDEX my_balance_table_multi_idx ON my_balance_table (account_id, updated_at DESC) INCLUDE (balance);

See:

Advantage of using INCLUDE as against adding the column in INDEX for covering index

Query
To optimize performance, cardinalities matter. How many rows total, how many distinct account_id, how many duplicates, how many missing days? Can there be multiple distinct rows per day? Is the table partitioned? Indexes, resources, etc.
Assuming many distinct account_id, few duplicates (only complete dupes like in your sample), few missing day, and we query for a single given account_id:
SELECT 7 AS account_id  -- same as filter !!!
     , (d.the_day AT TIME ZONE 'utc')::date AS date  -- don't depend on timezone !!!
     , b.updated_at
     , b.balance
FROM   generate_series(timestamptz '2024-03-01 0:0+0'   -- start-of-day for UTC !!!
                     , date_trunc('day', now(), 'UTC')  -- possibly off-by-1 !!!
                     , interval '1 day') AS d(the_day)
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT updated_at, balance 
   FROM   my_balance_table
   WHERE  account_id = 7  -- filter early !!!
   AND    updated_at < d.the_day + interval '1 day'  -- sargable !!!
   ORDER  BY updated_at DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) b ON true
ORDER  BY d.the_day;

fiddle
If this doesn't execute in ms (not seconds or minutes), then something isn't right. Consider hiring a consultant to look into that. :)
date_trunc() taking the time zone as 3rd parameter requires Postgres 12+.
There is a lot of fine print to get everything right.
Related:

Selecting today's rows based on UTC time

To process the whole table at once, instead of a single account, a variant of the second query in my related answer will perform better, and above index won't matter.

PostgreSQL: Generate a series of dates for each group in a table


thank you for this answer, the 15m i was talking about was when scanning the whole balance table and not only on account 7. This performance of 15m is still not acceptable and only grows in time as the the balance table grows, so I am interested in a solution to scan the full table with an acceptable performance

I tried the second query in your related answers (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133406/generate-a-series-of-dates-for-each-group-in-a-table), but it gives wrong value of balances in some cases (eg when the balance decreases and increases over the days)

for completeness, I just edited my post with the trial I did based on the first query from your related answer

@dada First things first: does my query work for a single given account_id? If so, how does performance  compare to what you had?

yes it works, and the performance is the same that i had previously, now the pb is the performance of the query using left join lateral over the full input table. Perhaps I should just bear with the 15m :)

@dada How many records does your table have? How many accounts? How many balances in the timeframe of the date series?

@dada If this takes seconds, not milliseconds, something is not right with your database. (You didn't even tell how long it takes.) To process the whole table at once, a different query is better. Your question only shows a single account, only in comments you mentioned to scan the full table. (Why would you do that?). I feel like I have done enough here. If this is about performance, provide information in your question as instructed in the [postgresql-performance] tag. Or hire a consultant.
